# Forking new repos

Tags: git, github

I have a monolith repository which has multiple microservices in it. I want to now create repos for each microservice in it but I don't want that microservice to lose its history. I thought forking would be the best way to do it, but github won't let me fork repos I am the owner off

So in short

1. Create a new Repo (While bringing history of old repo) with all services from monolith
2. In the new repo, delete all over microservices and keep just one of them
3. Remove the microservice from the monolith
4. Repeat

What's the best approach for this? Or will I just have to give up my history? (The monolith will be deleted once all microservices have their own repo's)

Comment: Your strategy is correct. Not super familiar w/ GitHub's UI but you may need to do it from a different tool such as the Git CLI by cloning and then pushing to a new repo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a git command for that, which is documented in [this help page](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository) on github :

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME  BRANCH-NAME
```

This command creates a new branch `BRANCH-NAME` in your current repo, which contains the history of `FOLDER-NAME`.

The github help page also gives you instruction on the steps to create a new repo and push that branch to this new repo.